# Windows CLI locks killer in Python

Tags: python, windows, cli

Some coworkers and I sometimes want to delete folders, only to get the very informative: "Permission Denied" message. I had discovered [Handle.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) and Process Explorer to help with this, but the method was still too manual and cumbersome.

Thus, I decided to write this Python CLI script to release locks on a given file. It runs Handle.exe under the hood and parses the output to prompt the user for confirmation to kill any given process (unless a quiet-like option flag is given).

We all work on Windows 7 using basically the same setup (IT takes care of setting up all the machines). The default Python is ActivateState's Python2.6.9. While some people use cmd.exe, a lot of guys use Bash or Cygwin, so I wanted to support all of these.

I am not sure if using `logging` solely for the purpose of adding a prefix to my output messages was a good idea, but it felt very redundant to add it to every `print`. Making a function that wraps `print` made the code look weird.

Also, I'm at a loss as to how to test this. I've added tests for `abspath` function (see repo), but I'm having trouble writing tests for the other functions.

```
"""Dammit let me delete this file!

Usage:
    dammit [-y | -s] <name>
    dammit (-h)

Options:
-y        Kill without permission.
-s        Enable hotkey
-h        Show this screen.

"""
from __future__ import print_function

from docopt import docopt
from functools import partial
import logging
import msvcrt
import os
import posixpath
import re
import subprocess
import sys
import time

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
PREFIX = 'dammit:'
formatter = logging.Formatter(PREFIX + ' %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(ch)

CYGPATH = ['C:\\GnuNT\\bin\\cygpath.exe']
HANDLE = ["handle64.exe"]
# handle.exe provides way to close specified handle, which would be preferable,
# but this requires administrator rights :(
KILL = ["TASKKILL", "/f", "/pid"]
ACTIVATE = ["activatePID.exe"]
EXPLORER = "explorer.exe"
CANT_EXECUTE = """Could not execute command: %s"""


def abspath(path):
    """Return the absolute path of given `path`.

    Taken to be relative from current working directory if input is not an
    absolute path.

    Args:
        path (str) : Pathname to absolutize.

    Notes:
        Should work for POSIX and Windows paths to accomodate
        different shells.
    """
    if posixpath.isabs(path):  # Starts with "/"
        if path[1:9] != 'cygdrive':
            path = posixpath.join('/cygdrive', path[1:])
        proc = subprocess.Popen(CYGPATH + ['-w', path],
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        return proc.stdout.read().rstrip()  # Remove trailing newline
    return os.path.abspath(path)


def find_locks(name):
    """Find which processes currently have a particular file/directory open.

    Args:
        name (str) : Name of the file which is locked.

    Returns:
        List of (process, PID)-pairs which are accessing the file.
    """
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(HANDLE + [name])
    except WindowsError:
        log.info(CANT_EXECUTE % HANDLE)
        sys.exit(1)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return None
    pattern = r"([^\s]+)(?:\s+)pid: ([0-9]{4})"
    return frozenset(re.findall(pattern, output))


def kill(pid):
    """Kill process with given PID

    Args:
        pid (str) : PID to kill
    """
    try:
        with open(os.devnull, 'w') as nul:
            subprocess.Popen(KILL + [str(pid)], stdout=nul, stderr=nul)
    except WindowsError:
        log.info(CANT_EXECUTE % KILL)
        sys.exit(1)
    return


def _activatePID(pid, enable_hotkeys):
    """Try to activate window associated with given process ID

    Args:
        pid (str) : PID of process to activate.
        enable_hotkeys (bool) : If True, Autohotkey will send "y" and "n"
            key presses to the prompt upon activating requested window.
    """
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(ACTIVATE + [pid, str(enable_hotkeys)])
    except WindowsError:
        log.info(CANT_EXECUTE % ACTIVATE)
    return


def query(process, pid, show_callback):
    """Query user to kill or show process.

    No invalid answers allowed.

    Args:
        process (str) : Process name
        pid (str) : Process PID
        show_callback (func(x)) : Ran when user answers "show"


    Answers:
        y : Kill process
        n : Do not kill process
        s : Try to show (activate) window linked to the process.

    Answering "show" does not exit the prompt.

    Returns:
        bool: True if yes, False if no.
    """
    question = " Kill process %s with PID %s [y/n/s]? " % (process, pid)
    sys.stdout.write(PREFIX + question)
    while True:
        answer = msvcrt.getch().lower()
        if answer == 'y':
            sys.stdout.write(answer+'\n')
            return True
        elif answer == 'n':
            sys.stdout.write(answer+'\n')
            return False
        elif answer == 's':
            sys.stdout.write(answer)
            show_callback(pid)
        else:
            sys.exit(1)


def open_explorer():
    """Open explorer.exe process."""
    # Just opening 'explorer.exe' merely launches a Windows Explorer window,
    # which is not the desired effect here.
    log.info("Re-opening %s" % EXPLORER)
    windir = os.environ['windir']
    subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(windir, EXPLORER))


def main():
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, options_first=True)
    name = arguments['<name>']
    quiet = arguments['-y']
    hotkeys = arguments['-s']

    activatePID = partial(_activatePID, enable_hotkeys=hotkeys)
    name_abspath = abspath(name)
    log.debug("name_abspath=%s" % name_abspath)
    locks = find_locks(name_abspath)
    if not locks:
        log.info("Nothing locking %s" % name_abspath)
        sys.exit(0)

    for process, pid in locks:
        if not quiet:
            do_kill = query(process, pid, show_callback=activatePID)
            if do_kill is not True:
                continue
        kill(pid)
        log.debug("Killed PID %s" % pid)
        if process == EXPLORER:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            open_explorer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I can only nitpick about `return` statements at the end of some functions that can be simply omitted,
and a `return None` that can be simplified to simply `return`.

Comment: Fixed in latest commit! I switched the `return None` to a `return []` because I find it conveys a clearer "I've found no locks for that name" than `return` or `return None`. Personal preference I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## String formatting

Generally, if you're using Python 2.6 or higher, you should be using the function [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) to format strings, rather than `%`. For example, this line in your code:

> ```
> question = " Kill process %s with PID %s [y/n/s]? " % (process, pid)
> ```

Could become this:

```
question = " Kill process {process} with PID {pid} [y/n/s]? ".format(
    process=process,
    pid=pid
)
```

Another example would be turning this:

> ```
> log.debug("Killed PID %s" % pid)
> ```

Into this:

```
log.debug("Killed PID {pid}".format(pid=pid))
```

---

## Miscellaneous

On a small note, strings like this:

> ```
> 'C:\\GnuNT\\bin\\cygpath.exe'
> ```

Can be prefixed with `r`, like this so that you can do this, and get rid of the double-backslashes:

```
r'C:\GnuNT\bin\cygpath.exe'
```

Anything like this:

> ```
> return None
> ```

Can simply be changed to this:

```
return
```

In the case of the `kill` function, the `return` at the end can be omitted completely.

---

Other than that, your code looks really nice and clean. Good job!

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually never sure if it's good practice to use raw strings.

Comment: @Kreger51 No problem! Usually, when I'm working with file paths, I find it easier to use raw strings.